# Android ObjectAnimator only animates first item

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, fade, objectanimator

Hy fellow Android programmers,

I have a problem with the background color fading animation of the ObjectAnimator. 
As you see, if I switch to a Fragment where each items background color should fade, only the first items background color does so.

[image: Only first items bg color fades]

That's the function

```
    public static void colorFade(View view, Resources res) {
    ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(view, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), res.getColor(R.color.counter_text_bg), 0xffccc);
    colorFade.setDuration(30000);
    colorFade.start();
}
```

which is called in the overridden getView function of the extended BaseAdapter:

```
public class CompetitionsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)          { [...] UiHelper.colorFade(view, activity.getResources()); [...]}
```

When I scroll on, each items bg color fades as wanted. I've only problems with these items, that are shown when the Fragment is created. So in the picture, item 1 fades, items 2, 3, 4 and 5 don't fade and all following items fade as intended. This behavior repeats for all other fragments where I added the animation.

The item layout is a RelativeLayout and the layout containing a the ListView is a LinearLayout.

I hope that someone of you already encountered that problem and I hope that the information suffices - if not, tell me :)

Thank you very much!